# Visual C#, Is the size of the barcode in Codesoft unchangable?

Tags: c#

I made a Codesoft label with a QR Code in it.

I tried the following things but the size of the Barcode remain unchanged!

Is there no way to change the size of the Barcode!?

```
LabelManager2.Application LabelCS = new LabelManager2.Application();
LabelManager2.Document Lab = LabelCS.Documents.Open(file);

Lab.DocObjects.Item("Barcode1").Height=3000;
Lab.DocObjects.Barcodes.Item("Barcode1").Height=3000;
Lab.DocObjects.Barcodes.Item("Barcode1").BarHeight=3000;
```

Much appreciated!!!

Comment: There is no tag for Codesoft, there is not links to an opensource project. My suggestion is this is better directed at the company who creates this software, you will get a faster response most likely